# Is there a name for non-Benders in the Avatar universe?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Is there an "official"/in-universe name (or slang) for people that can't bend within the world of Avatar?

I know Benders are just called benders:

> If you want to be a Bender, you have to let go of fear.
>   - Aang, s1 ep1

So Benders have I guess a semi-official term, but do non-Benders? Almost like an Avatar version of "Muggle".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are literally just known as "non-benders".

From Tenzin's opening monologue in the first episode of *Legend of Korra*:

> Avatar Aang and Fire Lord Zuko transformed the Fire Nation colonies into the United Republic of Nations, a society where **benders and non-benders** from all over the world could live together, in peace and harmony.

And a quote from Pema in that same episode, illustrating that non-benders refer to themselves by that term as well:

> All I want is one child like me, a nice **non-bender**, who doesn't blast wind in my face every five seconds.

As found by Valorum, the show's creators Michael Dante Dimartino and Bryan Konietzko [also referred to them as "non-benders"](https://www.darkhorse.com/Blog/796/interview-avatar-last-airbender-creator-michael-da) in an interview.

([source for the quotes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Quotes/TheLegendOfKorra) - obligatory TV Tropes warning)

Comment: And I thought it was bad when someone passed wind near me!

Comment: Ah, yet to do the Korra series, looking forward to it though :p but thank you, that clears things up. Wish there was some kinda slang of types, maybe create more lore/stories around more social-political ideas. I did stumble across the Equalists in the avatar wiki, saw it was in Korra though, so didn't really give it a read (in case of spoilers). Will accept this answer :p

Comment: Incidentally, just from browsing that quotes list, the Equalists don't seem to use the phrase "non-bender" very much - though I'm guessing that's because they want to create a society where *everyone* is a non-bender, and the term would then be obsolete.

Comment: https://www.comicsbeat.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-imbalance-part-2-interview-faith-erin-hicks-peter-wartman/  - referred to as non-benders by the artist in charge of the manga

Comment: https://www.darkhorse.com/Blog/796/interview-avatar-last-airbender-creator-michael-da - Referred to as non-benders by the creator of the animated series